# cmd.exe as a built-in application pool identity

Tags: iis, windows-command-prompt, psexec

My IIS web applications run using the built-in application pool identity `IIS APPPOOL\Foo`.

Is it possible to run a command-line in the context of `IIS APPPOOL\Foo` using psexec or some other tool?

There are various [blog entries](https://amoghnatu.net/2015/01/15/get-password-for-iis-application-pool-account/) out there showing how to get the password of an application pool, but they only apply if the application pool uses a specific Windows identitiy, not when the application pool uses the built-in `IIS APPPOOL\...` identity.

Comment: Background: The web application needs to access an external share and I'd like to store the credentials using `net use`.